# Android datatables

Tags: java, android

To put is simply my app requires up to date data from a database.

The app will download a JSON of the data on a few conditions:

- First run
- App notified of data change
- Data is more then a 5 min old(Sometimes change notifications don't go though)

Data size isn't really an issue, largest database we have is around 300KB(30KB after compression/deflating)

Downloading/decompressing the data takes no time at all, but then I need to display it in a table like format similar to http://www.datatables.net with searching and sorting.

Currently I use a TableLayout, create a row, then a TextView for each column, then adding a OnClickListener for each row so that data can be selected.

This works/looks fine but its horribly slow for any database greater then 100 lines for searching or sorting. It seems to be a render time issue.

I find it hard to believe that Android doesn't have a better way of handling this and I can't seem to find it.

**Ideas**

- Write my own datatables like view
- Render an HTML table inside single TextView and figure out a way to get click events from inside it?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @RC. The question is about an efficient way to display the rows, I presume :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works/looks fine but its horribly slow for any database greater
>   then 100 lines for searching or sorting. It seems to be a render time
>   issue.

Yes, it does seem like a horrible approach to display a lot of data. What you can do instead is use a `ListView` (or `RecyclerView`) that will display each row of data from your table in a custom view. This can be very easily created in XML. Given what you are trying to achieve, this would simply be a few `TextView`s arranged horizontally. Also, they have something called view recycling which will save you memory and amp up the performance.

As for sorting, have you considered using a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)? Can you not get the data as a sorted reply from your server itself and avoid sorting locally?

Comment: wow, thanks for the speedy reply.
Ill try this approach, due to the nature of the data I can't use a pre-made XML file. The database can have different columns from user to user.
Im assuming Ill also need to worry about column width myself then.

As far as sorting goes, I can do it server side but I wanted to see if I could do it client side to save processing time/bandwidth on the server.

Comment: Drawing this way worked so much better! Still need to do sorting/filtering but that is its own problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can consider a comparator. Saves a lot of trouble. If you post another question, let me know. I'd be willing to help.